# Basic iPhone App w/ Thumbnails, Full Images, Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to determine the best starting structure (navigation, windows based, something else) for my iPhone app. I'm a complete noob with everything Apple (just got the mini a couple days ago).

I currently have three apps on Android and want to port to iOS. The apps are very basic. Here's a quick description with fake examples.

1st Screen - 2 Buttons (Cat / Dog) - Users selects one (Dog)
2nd Screen - 6 thumbnails of Dogs (all visible on screen) - User selects one.
3rd Screen - Full image of user selected thumbnail. Full image is clickable.
4th Screen or pop up - If user clicks full image, a 3 second video clip (mp4) plays. After playing, automatically goes back to Full Image screen.

In XCode 4, what would be the best starting point? Navigation, Windows, Single View, or just blank and hammer it out?

Ideally, I would like this to be dynamic where I only create the basic views and variables based on the user selection drives what is displayed.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a screenshot or two of your Android apps would help us better here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with navigation based app but hide the navigation bar or at least the back button so that the user can't go back on their own. This will work well because you can get the nice slide animation between screens. And you can use multiple views easily so you don't have to worry about trying to cram all of your stuff into one view and animate it.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Looking the documentation on the Navigation Controller, this looks promising. Also, I think it will give the app a more apple feel compared to what I have on Android. thanks!